# I want to Hide trigger_Dag tab from Airflow web UI

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow,I want to hide trigger_Dag from web UI to make every one to use cli to trigger dag manually. help me with what all changes need to do it airflow.cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest for you would be to enabled RBAC (role-based access control) and then to restrict the right to run jobs. This way, people wouldn't be able to actually run anything from the UI:
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/add-new-role.html